# Windows 8 Metro style listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8

I'm building a wpf metro style application, but for the start, page I needed to create Windows 8 start screen like listbox in **windows 7** and **.NetFramework 4.0**.

I used Listbox and Wrappanel now, but as you see it's not clear!!!

[image]

Please help me to fill the blank cell.

**EDIT**
change place of buttons
[image]

Comment: What is not clear? How do you expect us to help?

Comment: The blank space is unwanted.
Just when I want to add more big button the layout will have more spaces.

Comment: Can't say "Metro" anymore :)

Comment: So you are looking for a way on how to make the tiles behave like Windows 8 start up when adjusting tiles?

Answer (score 4):

look at :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/370650/Simple-Metro-Style-Panorama-Control-for-WPF
by Sacha Barber

Comment: my application works good, I don't want change base of it. Just need complex layout to fix this problem

Comment: The article explains how to do the complex layout. That's what you need: some code to customize the layout.

Answer (score 2):

this is not trivial at all... even microsoft guys told me that on a recent training I had..

I recommend following the following article which has something very close to what you need!

http://tozon.info/blog/post/2012/09/01/Variable-sized-grid-items-in-Windows-8-apps.aspx

Hope it helps!

Comment: Another tutorial from Tim Heuer (one of the best devs on Metro I think) http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da65cc08-c4bf-4824-b483-9c8f53fb063c

Comment: Thanks man. That's what I need.
But I need it in windows 7 and visual studio 2010(.Net framework 4.0)!!!

Comment: But you can replicate the UI, there are no much differences, probably some animations but nothing too difficult, also the first link is not using anything from 4.5 I think... no async for example!

Answer (score 1):

[VariableSizeWrapGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid) does the trick :

```
<GridView>
  <GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VariableSizeWrapGrid ItemHeight="100" ItemWidth="150"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </GridView.ItemsPanel>   
</GridView>
```

Example of result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this required **Windows 8**

Comment: Hmmm, "I'm building a wpf **metro style application**" confused me. Maybe should you remove the microsoft-metro tag which is related to WinRT, and replace it with windows8 instead ?
For your problem, I think there is no built-in way to get this functionnality in WPF. You have to do your own Control.

Answer (score 0):

Use a WrapPanel for layout and you're done:

```
<ListBox>
  ...
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```