# C# WPF Metro Style Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

Im searching metro style listbox. Im looked too much page but i couldn't find. İ need help, I wanna find metro style listbox. İ have looked this : [Windows 8 Metro style listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815235/windows-8-metro-style-listbox)

Comment: I know it. But isn't helped

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice article which might intrest you
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/370650/Simple-Metro-Style-Panorama-Control-for-WPF

Notice it's a Panorama control.

Answer (score 0):

Mahapps has great Metro controls like what you're asking and very easy to use.
http://mahapps.com/controls/tile.html

good luck